# A Journey around the Web

Tags: cipher, connect-wall

Are you ready to embark on a (rather short) journey?

1. Word Wall - 6 groups of 3, with the answers forming 2 groups of 3. The final answers start with T and U. (They come together into a single thing, respectively)

```
penny miny spider cern bing chain wave bit car weakest page google fication hot_dog site scope ant tardigrade
```

(hot_dog is one thing)

2. Vigenère, but 36 with math addon key extension pack (I'm a programmer, in JS not lua).

```
gsp1mnjsin2yrlxmn2uvptmnyyvltmn2urlxinyuvlxir2uvptinyuvlxmn2yvltinyuvlxmnyuvlxinyyrptin2urltmnyurltmnyyrpxinyuvltin2urltiny
```

Comment: I have a feeling this puzzle isn't [self-contained](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6299/internet-wide-puzzles)...

Comment: @codewarrior0 This is just me, but IDK if the puzzle really isn't self-contained. Possibly the connect-wall could have something to do with the key to the Vigenère cipher?

Comment: The solution to the Vigenere is some kind of Google Forms link.

Comment: On the right track

Comment: This isn't self contained, if you would like for me to take it down please tell me; I didn't see that rule in the rulebook. Thank you for understanding, I wish you a great day.